# Not able to share/trigger parent component's click event in child component

Tags: angular, typescript, output, parent-child, eventemitter

I am new to angular, Here is my problem :-

I have a parent component in which i am calling a child component using , which has a click event attached. now i want to tringger the click event function in child component but getting an error.

Here is my code:-
parent.html:-

```
<button (click)="openPopup('second popup')">open2</button>
<app-popup>
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <button (click)="savePopup('second popup')">save</button>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
</app-popup>
```

parent.ts:-

```
openPopup(content:string) {
   this.content = content;
   this.popupModalService.openPopup(this.elRef);
}
```

app-popup.html:-

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" (click)="closePopup()">&times;</span>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

app-popup.ts

```
@Output() click: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
savePopup(data:string) {
   alert('clicked para' + data);
}
```

I want to define save popup function in app-popup.ts
on click, getting error : TimelineComponent.html:38 ERROR TypeError: _co.savePopup is not a function

Comment: Have you checked the demo?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

parent.html

```
<button (click)="openPopup('second popup')">open2</button>
<app-popup #popupRef>
    <button (click)="popupRefChild.savePopup('second popup')">save</button>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
</app-popup>
```

parent.ts

```
import { PopupComponent } from "../popup/popup.component";


@ViewChild("popupRef", { static: false }) popupRefChild: PopupComponent;
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pb3nf7?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: I want to call savePopup function without any error : here is the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1oaqk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts